# How to remove extra blank space in the bottom of RDLC report C#

Tags: c#, rdlc, receipt

I just want to ask on how to remove the extra blank spaces below the report? I am aiming to print a receipt like those in the supermarket. The height of the report must be dynamic based on the content. I hope there is someone out there can help me. :)

[image]

setting data to rdlc report
            public void print_now(BarcodeData data)
        {

```
        this.reportViewer2.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        this.reportViewer2.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("Materials", data.Materials));
        this.reportViewer2.LocalReport.SetParameters(
           new ReportParameter[] {
                new ReportParameter("Barcode","*"+data.Transaction.Barcode+"*"),
                new ReportParameter("Requestor",data.Transaction.Requestor),
                 new ReportParameter("DateRequested",data.Transaction.DateCreated),
                 new ReportParameter("Sewing",data.Transaction.Sewing),
                 new ReportParameter("Employeeid",data.Transaction.EmployeeId),
                 new ReportParameter("IpAddress",data.Transaction.IpAddress),
           }
           );



        this.reportViewer2.RefreshReport();


        //AutoPrint();    

    }
```

and my Report.rdlc

[image]

Comment: Can you show the report definition? Probably you have some section-footers visible

Comment: hi sir. i have updated above post and also i did not put footer for my Report.rdlc its just plain body without footer and header

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `Height` on **0** of the `InteractiveSize` property.
This will make your page height infinite and as result force everything on a single page.

[image]

If you're still having trouble with this, you should probably check that none of the report items have a `PageBreakAtStart` or `PageBreakAtEnd` property set to true.